# shell scripting pipline to a variable

Tags: shell

I have the following:

```
FILENAME=$1
cat $FILENAME | while read LINE
do
       response="$LINE" | cut -c1-14
       request="$LINE" | cut -c15-31
       difference=($response - $request)/1000
       echo "$difference"
done
```

When I run this script it returns blank lines. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Might be simpler in awk:

```
awk '{print ($1 - $2)/1000}' "$1"
```

I'm assuming that the first 14 chars and the next 17 chars are the first two blank-separated fields.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to:

```
response=`echo $LINE | cut -c1-14`
request=`echo $LINE | cut -c15-31`
difference=`expr $response - $request`
val=`expr $difference/1000`
```

Comment: I will try it. What the difference between a ` and an ' ?

Comment: The /1000 is printed out. I have put echo $val after val=`expr $difference/1000`

Comment: need spaces around the `/` -- expr needs to see it as a separate argument

Answer (score 0):

You are basically doing everything wrong ;)
This should be better:

```
FILENAME="$1"
cat "$FILENAME" | while read LINE
do
       response=$(echo "$LINE" | cut -c1-14) # or cut -c1-14 <<< "$line"
       request=$(echo "$LINE" | cut -c15-31)
       difference=$((($response - $request)/1000)
       echo "$difference"
done
```

Comment: did you try this? I get `sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('`. Good luck to all.

Comment: Try this: `difference=$(( (response - request)/1000 ))` -- note the shell only does integer arithmetic, so you might need `difference=$( bc -l <<< "($response - $request)/1000" )`

Comment: @shellter Fixed that. glennjackman: Right. Not sure if integer math is wanted though.